# Difference between pull and select in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

It seems like `dplyr::pull()` and `dplyr::select()` do the same thing. Is there a difference besides that `dplyr::pull()` only selects 1 variable?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could see `select` as an analogue of `[` or `magrittr::extract` and `pull` as an analogue of `[[` (or `$`) or `magrittr::extract2` for data frames (an analogue of `[[` for lists would be `purr::pluck`).

```
df <- iris %>% head
```

All of these give the same output:

```
df %>% pull(Sepal.Length)
df %>% pull("Sepal.Length")
a <- "Sepal.Length"; df %>% pull(!!quo(a))
df %>% extract2("Sepal.Length")
df %>% `[[`("Sepal.Length")
df[["Sepal.Length"]]

# all of them:
# [1] 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5.0 5.4
```

And all of these give the same output:

```
df %>% select(Sepal.Length)
a <- "Sepal.Length"; df %>% select(!!quo(a))
df %>% select("Sepal.Length")
df %>% extract("Sepal.Length")
df %>% `[`("Sepal.Length")
df["Sepal.Length"]
# all of them:
#   Sepal.Length
# 1          5.1
# 2          4.9
# 3          4.7
# 4          4.6
# 5          5.0
# 6          5.4
```

`pull` and `select` can take `literal`, `character`, or `numeric` indices, while the others take `character` or `numeric` only

One important thing is they differ on how they handle negative indices.

For `select` negative indices mean columns to drop.

For `pull` they mean count from last column.

```
df %>% pull(-Sepal.Length)
df %>% pull(-1)
# [1] setosa setosa setosa setosa setosa setosa
# Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
```

Strange result but `Sepal.Length` is converted to `1`, and column `-1` is `Species` (last column)

This feature is not supported by `[[` and `extract2` :

```
df %>% `[[`(-1)
df %>% extract2(-1)
df[[-1]]
# Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : 
#   attempt to select more than one element in get1index <real>
```

Negative indices to drop columns are supported by `[` and `extract` though.

```
df %>% select(-Sepal.Length)
df %>% select(-1)
df %>% `[`(-1)
df[-1]

#   Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 4         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 5         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 6         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Answer (score 26):

First, it makes sense to see what `class` each function creates.

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% pull(cyl) %>% class()
#> 'numeric'

mtcars %>% select(cyl) %>% class()
#> 'data.frame'
```

So `pull()` creates a vector -- which, in this case, is `numeric` -- whereas `select()` creates a data frame.

Basically, `pull()` is the equivalent to writing `mtcars$cyl` or `mtcars[, "cyl"]`, whereas `select()` removes all of the columns except for `cyl` but maintains the data frame structure