quarter() function is giving Error in as.POSIXlt.default(x, tz = tz(x)) : do not know how to convert 'x' to class “POSIXlt”
I'm attempting to create a table counting the number of people engaged with per fiscal quarter using the quarter() function of the lubridate package.
For troubleshooting purposes, this is the reproducible dataset (simplified):
structure(list(`ID Number` = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
), `Date Record Created` = structure(c(1624492800, 
1624492800, 1624579200, 1624924800, 1625788800, 1627948800, 1628208000, 
1629244800, 1629849600, 1629849600), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"))), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

According to its documentation (https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/quarter.html), the quarter() function can "take a date-time object of class POSIXct, POSIXlt, Date, chron, yearmon, yearqtr, zoo, zooreg, timeDate, xts, its, ti, jul, timeSeries, fts or anything else that can be converted with as.POSIXlt". The date column I selected is formatted as POSIXct, and a character check yielded the following output:
str(peopledata$`Date Record Created`)
 POSIXct[1:339], format: "2021-06-24" "2021-06-24" "2021-06-25" "2021-06-29" "2021-07-09" "2021-08-03" "2021-08-06" "2021-08-18" "2021-08-25" "2021-08-25" ...

I ran this function to get to the point of grouping up the dates into their fiscal quarters:
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

people<-peopledata%>% 
  select(`ID Number`,`Date Record Created`)%>%
  quarter(`Date Record Created`,with_year=TRUE)

When I run the function, I get the following error:
Error in as.POSIXlt.default(x, tz = tz(x)) : 
  do not know how to convert 'x' to class “POSIXlt”
> traceback()
8: stop(gettextf("do not know how to convert '%s' to class %s", 
       deparse1(substitute(x)), dQuote("POSIXlt")), domain = NA)
7: as.POSIXlt.default(x, tz = tz(x))
6: as.POSIXlt(x, tz = tz(x))
5: month(as.POSIXlt(x, tz = tz(x))$mon + 1, label, abbr, locale = locale)
4: month.default(x)
3: month(x)
2: quarter(., `Date Record Created`, with_year = TRUE)
1: peopledata %>% select(`ID Number`, `Date Record Created`) %>% 
       quarter(`Date Record Created`, with_year = TRUE)

I attempted to then go back to the source data and run an as.Date() conversion on the column, and it threw a different error:
Input:
peopledata<-read_excel("../People Activity.xlsx", sheet='People', col_names = T, col_types = NULL, na="", skip = 0)%>% 
  filter_all(any_vars(!is.na(.)))%>% 
  as.Date(`Date Record Created`, format = '%Y-%m-%d')

Error and Traceback:
Error in as.Date.default(., `Date Record Created`, format = "%Y-%m-%d") : 
  do not know how to convert '.' to class “Date”
> traceback()
4: stop(gettextf("do not know how to convert '%s' to class %s", 
       deparse1(substitute(x)), dQuote("Date")), domain = NA)
3: as.Date.default(., `Date Record Created`, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
2: as.Date(., `Date Record Created`, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
1: read_excel("../People Activity.xlsx", 
       sheet = "People", col_names = T, col_types = NULL, 
       na = "", skip = 0) %>% filter_all(any_vars(!is.na(.))) %>% 
       as.Date(`Date Record Created`, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
> 

Where am I going wrong here?

You can reduce this to posting a subset of your peopledata  , and preferably also posting the result of  foo <- select( ....)   -- and what package select comes from.      In addition,   try traceback() so you know where this is popping up.

When this is reopened this may become an answer.  The problem is the tibble (disclaimer: I hate tibbles)  contains what looks like POSIX stuff, but  each entry in the  Nx2 tibble is actually a list element, so the POSIX data is, e.g.  foo[1,2][[1]] , and apparently lubridate doesn't "unpack" tibbles.    ---- or maybe it's as simple as NOT building a list for your initial structure ?

Here's what I did to make lubridate happy:      barf <- selected_output   class(barf) <- 'data.frame'   barz <- quarter(barf$Date Record Created, with_year=TRUE)  where "selected_output" is the result of the select operation

@CarlWitthoft: I didn't try your code, but it worked fine for me when I converted the  tibble to data.frame and selected the column normally. I usually avoid all tidyverse stuff.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49844902/difference-between-pull-and-select-in-dplyr

If you use pull instead of select, it works:
peopledata %>% 
  pull(`Date Record Created`) %>% 
  quarter(., type="year.quarter")

#>  [1] 2021.2 2021.2 2021.2 2021.2 2021.3 2021.3 2021.3 2021.3 2021.3 2021.3

